# Extend Ubuntu virtual disk partition in absence of a swap partition

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, gparted

On a Windows 10 laptop, I installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso) on VirtualBox 6.1.28.  I alloted 20GB to the virtual disk, but am running out of room.  I followed [this page](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=50661) to resize the virtual disk to 40GB.

I tried to follow the 3 pages below to extend the partition used by Ubuntu.  They all refer to a swap partition.

**Is there a dummy's process to extend my Ubuntu partition in the absence of a swap partition?**

Here are the 3 pages I tried to follow...

**[(1) Use `gparted` in a live running Ubuntu VM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407090/163540)**

[image]

I can't follow the procedure because I have no line item that corresponds to a swap partition (at least not that I recognize).  I assume that sda5 is my main file system since it is 20GB and mostly used.  I right-clicked it and chose "Resize/Move".

[image]

The new size "19965" seems suspiciously close to the original 20GB size, so I entered 2x that amount (39930).  Unfortunately, it is not accepted.  If I press `Return` or `Tab`, it reverts back to 19965.  I can't simply click the "Resize" button because it is grayed out.

**[(2) Use `fdisk -l`](https://askubuntu.com/a/520721/1505171)**

The result of `df -h` is:

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev       1.9G    0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs      394M 1.3M  393M   1% /run
/dev/sda5   20G  15G  3.4G  82% /
tmpfs      2.0G 6.2M  2.0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs      5.0M 4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs      2.0G    0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0 128K 128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2  56M  56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop3 219M 219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop1  56M  56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2246
/dev/loop4  66M  66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop5  51M  51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop6  33M  33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
/dev/loop7  33M  33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/13640
/dev/loop8  66M  66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/sda1  511M 4.0K  511M   1% /boot/efi
User.Name  476G 237G  240G  50% /media/sf_User.Name
tmpfs      394M  48K  394M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0    59M  59M     0 100% /media/lnxadmin/VBox_GAs_6.1.28
```

I didn't follow the subsequent `fdisk -l` because it makes reference to a swap partition, which I don't have.  Plus, it refers to VM Workstation, which I do not have.

**[(3) Use `fdisk /dev/sda`](https://askubuntu.com/a/116367/1505171)**

After launching the `fdisk` app using `fdisk /dev/sda`, I entered `p` to see the partitions:

```
Device    Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1 *       2048  1050623  1048576  512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2      1052670 41940991 40888322 19.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5      1052672 41940991 40888320 19.5G 83 Linux
```

Again, I have no swap partition.  Since the procedure refers to a swap partition, I abandoned this as well.

Comment: You will need to first expand `/dev/sda2` to use the 40GB, *then* expand `/dev/sda5` 

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go. I suspect that I have to be very precise. For sda5, can I simply double the 19965 to 39930? I'm not sure if it matters, but the current size of sda2 slightly different from sda5 -- sda2 is 19966 MiB (but can be extended to 40446 MiB).

Comment: The precision is handled by the system. Just have the partitions use the full space, and the software will handle the rest 

Comment: @matigo: It works!  Thanks!!  There are probably many people like me who move to an Ubuntu VM out of necessity, but without any Linux experience.  Your comment can probably save them a *ton* of time.  Would you please post it as an answer?  Maybe with a (very brief) explanation of what it means for a partition to be a subordinate of another (e.g., sda2 under sda5)?